# How to symbolicate crash report for a Ad-Hoc publish

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I have published my app by ad-hoc for my testers. I do not archive this, but I have the .ipa file and the .provisioning file that sent to tester.

Tester said that app crash after he go to on of the screens. I have a log system in my app that save's exceptions for me in a text file. I asked him to send me this log file.

He send the log file and the file include this block:

```
    Incident Identifier: 6AA332CD-4719-4CEF-A53F-D82489F12023
CrashReporter Key: 299fdc42c5a3a6a02c44cf60cd96a3d784c55e80
Hardware Model: iPhone3,1
Process: Realtyna_iPhone_Project [112]
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/3FD224E1-D55E-452D-A24C-343205589451/Realtyna_iPhone_Project.app/Realtyna_iPhone_Project
Identifier: Realtyna_iPhone_Project
Version: ??? (???)
Code Type: ARM (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2013-07-01 18:02:39.249 +0200
OS Version: iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread: 0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3129f29e 0x38f4497a 0x3129ef94 0x320cc3c4 0x1737d0 0x233a64 0x24335c 0x3f4de4 0x4c605e 0x5217a2 0x4b536a 0x3310e30c 0x33148d10 0x3312682a 0x331264b2 0x330bcaae 0x331318ea 0x32e66bfc 0x3935b4b2 0x3935cdc6 0x31272f36 0x311e5eb8 0x311e5d44 0x34da92e6 0x330fb2fc 0x174a80 0x1fbc8c 0x3f4de4 0x4c605e 0x5217a2 0x524286 0x52750a 0x4d8772 0x56537c 0x3937bb1c)

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x39442350 0x39431000 + 70480
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x393b911e 0x3938a000 + 192798
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x393f596e 0x3938a000 + 440686
3 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004fe348 0x1000 + 5231432
4 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x0052ac54 0x1000 + 5413972
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x393c2e90 0x3938a000 + 233104
6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x393b911e 0x3938a000 + 192798
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x393f596e 0x3938a000 + 440686
8 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x00572384 0x1000 + 5706628
9 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004fbede 0x1000 + 5222110
10 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004c41ea 0x1000 + 4993514
11 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004fdf80 0x1000 + 5230464
12 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004fe04c 0x1000 + 5230668
13 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x00529f10 0x1000 + 5410576
14 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004486fc 0x1000 + 4486908
15 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x005723d0 0x1000 + 5706704
16 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x00572480 0x1000 + 5706880
17 CoreFoundation 0x3129f57c 0x311dd000 + 796028
18 libobjc.A.dylib 0x38f44a62 0x38f3c000 + 35426
19 libc++abi.dylib 0x38991078 0x38990000 + 4216
20 libc++abi.dylib 0x38991110 0x38990000 + 4368
21 libc++abi.dylib 0x3899250e 0x38990000 + 9486
22 libobjc.A.dylib 0x38f449ba 0x38f3c000 + 35258
23 CoreFoundation 0x3129ef94 0x311dd000 + 794516
24 MapKit 0x320cc3c4 0x320a6000 + 156612
25 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x001737d0 0x1000 + 1517520
26 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x00233a64 0x1000 + 2304612
27 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x0024335c 0x1000 + 2368348
28 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x003f4de4 0x1000 + 4144612
29 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004c6060 0x1000 + 5001312
30 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x005217a4 0x1000 + 5375908
31 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004b536a 0x1000 + 4932458
32 UIKit 0x3310e30c 0x330a4000 + 434956
33 UIKit 0x33148d10 0x330a4000 + 675088
34 UIKit 0x3312682a 0x330a4000 + 534570
35 UIKit 0x331264b2 0x330a4000 + 533682
36 UIKit 0x330bcaae 0x330a4000 + 101038
37 UIKit 0x331318ea 0x330a4000 + 579818
38 QuartzCore 0x32e66bfc 0x32e51000 + 89084
39 libdispatch.dylib 0x3935b4b4 0x3935a000 + 5300
40 libdispatch.dylib 0x3935cdc6 0x3935a000 + 11718
41 CoreFoundation 0x31272f36 0x311dd000 + 614198
42 CoreFoundation 0x311e5eb8 0x311dd000 + 36536
43 CoreFoundation 0x311e5d44 0x311dd000 + 36164
44 GraphicsServices 0x34da92e6 0x34da4000 + 21222
45 UIKit 0x330fb2fc 0x330a4000 + 357116
46 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x00174a80 0x1000 + 1522304
47 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x001fbc8c 0x1000 + 2075788
48 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x003f4de4 0x1000 + 4144612
49 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004c6060 0x1000 + 5001312
50 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x005217a4 0x1000 + 5375908
51 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x00524286 0x1000 + 5386886
52 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x0052750a 0x1000 + 5399818
53 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x004d8772 0x1000 + 5076850
54 Realtyna_iPhone_Project 0x0056537c 0x1000 + 5653372
55 libdyld.dylib 0x3937bb1c 0x3937a000 + 6940

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x39432648 0x39431000 + 5704
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x3936b4ec 0x3935a000 + 70892
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x3935ddf4 0x3935a000 + 15860

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
r0: 0x00000000 r1: 0x00000000 r2: 0x00000000 r3: 0x3aefb534
r4: 0x00000006 r5: 0x3aefbb88 r6: 0x0058206a r7: 0x2fdfd29c
r8: 0x00000000 r9: 0x00000000 r10: 0x00582088 r11: 0x00beeed4
ip: 0x00000148 sp: 0x2fdfd290 lr: 0x393b9123 pc: 0x39442350
cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0x1000 - 0x5d4fff +Realtyna_iPhone_Project armv7 /var/mobile/Applications/3FD224E1-D55E-452D-A24C-343205589451/Realtyna_iPhone_Project.app/Realtyna_iPhone_Project
0x2fe62000 - 0x2fe82fff dyld armv7 <280610df5ed43ec7aa00629a27009302> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3020c000 - 0x302ddfff RawCamera armv7 <8752cce31e8e3ceab5d88c84e3481db2> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x302e6000 - 0x303b6fff IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7 /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
0x303c0000 - 0x304a6fff AVFoundation armv7 <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x304a7000 - 0x304a7fff Accelerate armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x304a8000 - 0x305e6fff vImage armv7 <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x305e7000 - 0x306cafff libBLAS.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x306cb000 - 0x30980fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7 <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x30981000 - 0x309dafff libvDSP.dylib armv7 <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x309db000 - 0x309ecfff libvMisc.dylib armv7 <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x309ed000 - 0x309edfff vecLib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x309ee000 - 0x309fffff Accounts armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x30a01000 - 0x30a65fff AddressBook armv7 <8cfae84dc66d3c1f9d17335c53c3d7b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30a66000 - 0x30b20fff AddressBookUI armv7 <0017d0a0c2593522acaaa0eee41775e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x30c6b000 - 0x30ef3fff AudioToolbox armv7 <394ee11cf826367db9ff4968dbc71d6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x30ef4000 - 0x30fb9fff CFNetwork armv7 <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30fba000 - 0x31010fff CoreAudio armv7 <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31024000 - 0x311dcfff CoreData armv7 <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x311dd000 - 0x3130ffff CoreFoundation armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31310000 - 0x31448fff CoreGraphics armv7 <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3144a000 - 0x31485fff libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31669000 - 0x31684fff libRIP.A.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x31685000 - 0x3173afff CoreImage armv7 <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x3173b000 - 0x31793fff CoreLocation armv7 <4edb4b0f05e13af8b84699fe3ea4c538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x317c8000 - 0x3182dfff CoreMedia armv7 <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3182e000 - 0x318b6fff CoreMotion armv7 <4512d901170d32e7842e7fc1c519386b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x318b7000 - 0x3190dfff CoreTelephony armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3190e000 - 0x31970fff CoreText armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x31971000 - 0x31980fff CoreVideo armv7 <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x31981000 - 0x31a35fff EventKit armv7 <99a7a1603323319f9e24f97e9f89bfd3> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x31b05000 - 0x31cc8fff Foundation armv7 <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31e83000 - 0x31eccfff IOKit armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31ecd000 - 0x320a5fff ImageIO armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x320a6000 - 0x3211efff MapKit armv7 <027e730f45cc3868b98833546bb55449> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x3211f000 - 0x322b9fff MediaPlayer armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x322ba000 - 0x32534fff MediaToolbox armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32535000 - 0x325bbfff MessageUI armv7 <8dbc0a8e6a253c8c8d6301064f23dfea> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x325bc000 - 0x32615fff MobileCoreServices armv7 <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x32642000 - 0x32703fff GLEngine armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x32704000 - 0x3270bfff OpenGLES armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3270d000 - 0x3270dfff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7 <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3270e000 - 0x32710fff libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7 <761c0f0e263c3d39adbb5bf789cedde1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x32711000 - 0x32713fff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x32714000 - 0x32718fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32719000 - 0x32756fff libGLImage.dylib armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x32757000 - 0x3287cfff libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7 <0b3cb1b9a5003c4a975ec268cabca3fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x32e51000 - 0x32f66fff QuartzCore armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32f67000 - 0x32fb4fff QuickLook armv7 <954e3a8bdaf337b085b30fd514ea5f3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x32fb5000 - 0x32fe3fff Security armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x33062000 - 0x330a1fff SystemConfiguration armv7 <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x330a4000 - 0x335f8fff UIKit armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x335f9000 - 0x33637fff VideoToolbox armv7 /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x338cd000 - 0x338d9fff AccountSettings armv7 <8db45acc4d3d3017af10fa5ee82c2306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x33920000 - 0x33923fff ActorKit armv7 <5dfc59258ea63006be9c542e5fafbc45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x33925000 - 0x33928fff AggregateDictionary armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x33a11000 - 0x33a24fff AirTraffic armv7 <752b64045f4d3ea88a946b53b731ce1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x33a25000 - 0x33d31fff Altitude armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Altitude.framework/Altitude
0x33d54000 - 0x33d8ffff AppSupport armv7 <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x33d90000 - 0x33db4fff AppleAccount armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x33dc1000 - 0x33dcefff ApplePushService armv7 <8bad4a9300db3d4d8555535f25c32da4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x33e02000 - 0x33e0bfff AssetsLibraryServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33e26000 - 0x33e3dfff BackBoardServices armv7 <772912697ec23e5199a452e97f075dd9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x33e47000 - 0x33e6bfff Bom armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x33eeb000 - 0x33ef2fff CaptiveNetwork armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x33ef3000 - 0x33fbdfff Celestial armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x33fca000 - 0x33fcefff CertUI armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x340a1000 - 0x340a6fff CommonUtilities armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x3412b000 - 0x3415bfff ContentIndex armv7 <00ed488e47ee34ca9f01f2cc911f453c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3436c000 - 0x3436dfff CoreSurface armv7 <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x343da000 - 0x343dffff CrashReporterSupport armv7 <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x343e0000 - 0x3441cfff DataAccess armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x345b1000 - 0x345c3fff DataAccessExpress armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x34602000 - 0x34603fff DataMigration armv7 <5903e08348b83f119022cbbf83ad100a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x34606000 - 0x3461ffff DictionaryServices armv7 <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x34627000 - 0x3463ffff EAP8021X armv7 <6d5ab53850e23fe389e64e2705bd7810> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3464f000 - 0x34653fff FTClientServices armv7 <6354e5b30919340db3b976312b284fce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x34654000 - 0x34691fff FTServices armv7 <89c066d12a6031038a9b8c61221abc0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x34692000 - 0x34aa5fff FaceCoreLight armv7 <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34af2000 - 0x34af7fff libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7 <4366fa0d1a0938a794bd8346e286d6f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x34c9d000 - 0x34ca9fff GenerationalStorage armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x34caa000 - 0x34da3fff GeoServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x34da4000 - 0x34daffff GraphicsServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x34e1e000 - 0x34e99fff HomeSharing armv7 <280b77b71df23f1cb5c9a2b76fc53212> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x34e9a000 - 0x34ea4fff IAP armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34f5c000 - 0x34fd4fff IMCore armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x3509b000 - 0x350e7fff IMFoundation armv7 <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x350ee000 - 0x350effff IOAccelerator armv7 <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x350f0000 - 0x350f5fff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x350f6000 - 0x350fafff IOSurface armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35144000 - 0x352eafff JavaScriptCore armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3531b000 - 0x35351fff MIME armv7 <57a1db0d5d3237708f54b3bd83553bae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x35390000 - 0x3539afff MailServices armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x353b6000 - 0x3540efff ManagedConfiguration armv7 <44bbb2ba85c8320bb9e73c654b90f8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3540f000 - 0x35414fff Marco armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x35425000 - 0x3549bfff MediaControlSender armv7 <9fb205b64b5333a495ac61c149e0304b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x3549c000 - 0x354a5fff MediaRemote armv7 <73da55e989e73cb9ad6e9fdd4604ecc3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x35518000 - 0x355d1fff Message armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x355da000 - 0x355dcfff MessageSupport armv7 <81eb34b663513745b0ed65e244c7ab0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x355e5000 - 0x35612fff MobileAsset armv7 <3a9e6258ae1230f5b12f1638b09cb974> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x3563f000 - 0x3564efff MobileDeviceLink armv7 <817380030c613284a12074d960087522> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x35657000 - 0x3565afff MobileInstallation armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3565b000 - 0x35661fff MobileKeyBag armv7 <35882c57076334aeb0641969a9b69ff3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3569a000 - 0x356bdfff MobileSync armv7 <1edd78024ae13e9997972ee905bc944e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x356be000 - 0x356c1fff MobileSystemServices armv7 <10b4eee2739c353183ac2cfe4e39a443> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x356d9000 - 0x356e2fff MobileWiFi armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x356fc000 - 0x35840fff MusicLibrary armv7 <3870f4cb0c8b36778ad1a3f7556547f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x35858000 - 0x35871fff Notes armv7 <3d4a8d4b012a3743b0ffc8dc33fb79e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x35872000 - 0x35874fff OAuth armv7 <575df12a2f2436af92e31494c3b74465> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x35fae000 - 0x35fd3fff OpenCL armv7 <9baf655cae4e3f9f99a5c6a99207099d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x36334000 - 0x36351fff PersistentConnection armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x365e7000 - 0x3660ffff PrintKit armv7 <3f0b9c58a458358eb506858e8ff9e1fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x36610000 - 0x36684fff ProofReader armv7 <9cb25467554637bcb268ba30527d3c0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36685000 - 0x3668dfff ProtocolBuffer armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x367c9000 - 0x367dafff SpringBoardServices armv7 <0e48e91ad40f34aab3323c7c4157ce52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3683c000 - 0x36917fff StoreServices armv7 <6d45f42eff2736d18cdd81af0473dd5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x36965000 - 0x36967fff TCC armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x36986000 - 0x36993fff TelephonyUtilities armv7 <803d7a92439238ee942086999c481eb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x36e16000 - 0x36eb6fff UIFoundation armv7 <9a464526e26634bc834537e5ac3abf1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x36ed5000 - 0x37053fff VectorKit armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit
0x371ba000 - 0x371d9fff WebBookmarks armv7 <77b65bc9c87b367ebea9a5b7984b13a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x371da000 - 0x37b09fff WebCore armv7 <06c849df1ad435aeb8b6130d85cee5df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x37b0a000 - 0x37be7fff WebKit armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x37c92000 - 0x37c99fff XPCObjects armv7 <723fe314ab95381cbfa69a0000005692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x37dec000 - 0x37e27fff iCalendar armv7 <1c4486846efd3c9480174d9e7df8cec6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x37f3e000 - 0x37f76fff iTunesStore armv7 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x387b9000 - 0x387bffff libAccessibility.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x387c0000 - 0x387d6fff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7 <5a8a3d18a1ff3c97bd773705fef2d81c> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x387ee000 - 0x387fafff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3880c000 - 0x3880cfff libSystem.B.dylib armv7 <7aeeab280f7e361e9986d962d0fa5281> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3892e000 - 0x3893afff libbsm.0.dylib armv7 <3870b1c8b1783b788bd51da1a04eae6e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3893b000 - 0x38944fff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x38945000 - 0x3898ffff libc++.1.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x38990000 - 0x389a3fff libc++abi.dylib armv7 <4b8520bc534231ae97ce146e076bc7bf> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x389d4000 - 0x38ac1fff libiconv.2.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x38ac2000 - 0x38c0bfff libicucore.A.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x38c13000 - 0x38c13fff liblangid.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x38c16000 - 0x38c1dfff liblockdown.dylib armv7 <224c65d491603e21a78a00af9e10f012> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x38c1e000 - 0x38c33fff liblzma.5.dylib armv7 <4a1f38cbee783a9ea6de94af25d45cc1> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x38efe000 - 0x38f13fff libmis.dylib armv7 <7502589f14733beb963c542fa40438c8> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x38f3c000 - 0x3903afff libobjc.A.dylib armv7 <79e5d714945834e4b2587abfc6c7269c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x390fe000 - 0x39113fff libresolv.9.dylib armv7 <3ee61a04a99b322e97e179bc03c46cf1> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x39138000 - 0x391bdfff libsqlite3.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x391be000 - 0x39209fff libstdc++.6.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3920a000 - 0x39230fff libtidy.A.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x39234000 - 0x392e1fff libxml2.2.dylib armv7 <28dcf6ee713b387ebb763d11d4b3cd37> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x392e2000 - 0x39302fff libxslt.1.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x39303000 - 0x3930ffff libz.1.dylib armv7 <3ea49513bc023326be68e35324c11d0e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x39310000 - 0x39313fff libcache.dylib armv7 <91862e82d5063531b4fb4da9a19e5365> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x39314000 - 0x3931afff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3931b000 - 0x3931dfff libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7 <6ac449c92d743640a23d9d1ebe0b48a9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3931e000 - 0x39323fff libcopyfile.dylib armv7 <87bcae8743ab35c8a070ac95b7d57acb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x39324000 - 0x39359fff libcorecrypto.dylib armv7 <04b464137fc2304b84eeed1a5418f4a8> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3935a000 - 0x39377fff libdispatch.dylib armv7 <9323bb560d4e3a3fb41efdc78bd0cf94> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x39378000 - 0x39379fff libdnsinfo.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3937a000 - 0x3937bfff libdyld.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3937c000 - 0x3937cfff libkeymgr.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3937d000 - 0x39382fff liblaunch.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x39383000 - 0x39386fff libmacho.dylib armv7 <965ab939e24935e7a3a65981574a7745> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x39387000 - 0x39388fff libremovefile.dylib armv7 <295706037a5238b4aa145df7b9354a0e> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x39389000 - 0x39389fff libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7 <50a01a02f573317fbd21e1070b0afc7d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3938a000 - 0x39410fff libsystem_c.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x39411000 - 0x39417fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7 <6c5ac17133a1366aaeea5dc38dceaf1f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x39418000 - 0x39430fff libsystem_info.dylib armv7 <5a4a4c9da868317db7f17cb616eb32d1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x39431000 - 0x39447fff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7 <7d409890411a396a9c812f488f8ea99a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x39448000 - 0x39464fff libsystem_m.dylib armv7 <036ea0321da038e8b69a0c4413da00fe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x39465000 - 0x39473fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x39474000 - 0x3947bfff libsystem_notify.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x3947c000 - 0x3947dfff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7 <45bb99d46408351a9c61b5326032adea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3947e000 - 0x3947efff libunwind.dylib armv7 /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3947f000 - 0x39494fff libxpc.dylib armv7 <7f983066ea4c3c119f3e2344a04fef6e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

I searched web about this error and find that it is a crash log that accord when app faced with a no handled exception. As I found normally this file send to developer as .crash file but I have not .crash file for symbolizing this exception. so how can symbolicate this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the given content into a file with the extension "crash", drag it into the organizers `Device Logs` menu under `Library` and let it do the symbolication.

Once it symbolicated it, and all the required data (correct dSYM files for that build) is available, you should see the methods and line numbers in your app that lead to this exception.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I change the extension to .crash and drag the file to the device log section but after symbolicating the file not changed. I think it because that xcode have no correct dSYM file. I have the .ipa file, is there any way to symbolicate this log file?

Comment: If you don't have the dSYM there is no way to get your code symbolicated. See this article to find out how to find the correct dSYM: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/how-tos-faq/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems